# Open shift Pod Memory is not releasing for Java tomcat application | No Memory Leak in application

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, cloud, openshift

I have a java tomcat application deployed on open shift environment and I have observed pod memory is not releasing even after the load has stopped (No Traffic). I have waited till 1 day but still,  memory not released due to which pods are never scaling down. In HPA properties also, utilized memory is above 80%.

**I have already analyzed the heap dump of application and there is no memory leak at all, also never observed any out of memory error/exception.**

Tried using below JVM props which I found on open shift blog (given below) but still the problem is not resolved.
https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/scaling-java-containers

**About Application**
It's bit of traditional application (Advance Java & Servlets) built in monolithic architecture and using tomcat 8 as a application server.

*It'd be really helpful if anyone can help or share their expertise in scaling java application on open shift.*

Comment: Are you expecting the JVM to release memory back to the OS? I've never seen that happen, and rightly so: you just configure what it is allowed to consume (max)

Comment: If memory is not given back then HPA will never scale down the pods, because it has some threshold for it. 
How can I achieve it then ? if memory doesn't release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way that the Java JVM works: it never releases memory. And, assuming a modern JVM, it will generally just allocate as much memory as available in the container on startup. There are a bunch of reasons for this, but the gist of it is that the JVM is doing its own memory management and memory garbage collection so it needs to have as big of a pool of memory available as it can.

As such, memory usually isn't the best option for autoscaling Java applications. Typically you will want to autoscale based on CPU and just set the amount of memory for each pod based on load testing (and generally set memory request to the same amount as memory limit). e.g. If I have a CPU request size of 2000 mCPU, I'll do performance benchmarking on a 2000 mCPU container and gradually reduce the available memory until I notice a degradation in performance or unacceptable GC. That then establishes my pod resources and I can use HPA to scale up and down based on CPU.

Standard disclaimers apply: performance tuning is a very application specific thing. But autoscaling Java based applications on memory usage isn't going to work effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation David.

So all java applications only uses CPU condition in their HPA. Is it a good approach to remove memory condition and only scale on the basis of CPU usage ?

Comment: Yes, that would be my approach, scaling only on cpu and not memory. The word “all” always scares me, I’m sure someone somewhere has an exception, but I’ve always used cpu only.